# find and replace specific json data in python?

Tags: python, json

I am trying to replace data1 with data5 in json body of Full Address, but my code is giving error with these (list indices must be integers or slices, not str).

Please see my code as well as json body below.

**json**

```
[
   {
       "fields": {
           "Full Address": "data1",
           "pl/p/0": "212152",
           "ot": "fgde"
       }
   },
   {
       "fields": {
        "Full Address": "data2",
        "pl/p/0": "52562",
        "ot": "frtfr"
       }
   }
]
```

**code**

```
import json
with open('jsonbody.json') as f:
data = json.load(f)

  for item in data['fields']:
  item['Full Address'] = item['Full Address'].replace('data1', 'data5')

with open('new_data.json', 'w') as f:
 json.dump(data, f)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the `data` is list, and its element is a dict, which contains `fields` key

```py
import json
with open('jsonbody.json') as f:
    data = json.load(f)

for item in data:
    item['fields']['Full Address'] = item['fields']['Full Address'].replace('data1', 'data5')

with open('new_data.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(data, f)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here I am answering my own question with adding german umlaut detail.

```
 import json 
  jsonbody = 'jsonbody.encode()'
  with open('jsonbody.json', 'r') as file:
 json_data = json.load(file)
 for item in json_data:
       if item['fields']['Full Address'] in ["data1"]:
          item['fields']['Full Address'] = "data5_Ä"
          
   with open('new_data.json', 'w') as file:
    json.dump(json_data, file, indent=2)
 # if my detail contain german words then I will use this
     json.dump(json_data, file, indent=2, ensure_ascii=False)
```